# Apache FOP AFP to XML conversion

Tags: java, xml, pdf, apache-fop, afp

I am looking for a Java API that provides functionality that will convert AFP(IBM Advanced Function Presentation)formatted documents to xml or pdf. I am trying to implement Apache FOP 1.1, but there is hardly no implementation documentation with regard to AFP's and there are no tutorials or examples, anywhere. I would sure appreciate any direction with regard to this endeavor.

Answer (score 2):

Apache FOP supports producing AFP. It does not provide any functionality to process existing AFP files. As for converting AFP files to other formats, [Compart](http://www.compart.com/en/products) has very good tools in that area.

Comment: +1.Compart tools are quit good.I had good feedback from MPI FastParser users too (https://www.mpitech.fr/mpitech.nsf/pages/afp-fast-parser_fr.html)